# Detect mouse is near circle edge

Tags: javascript, math

I have a function which gets the mouse position in world space, then checks to see if the mouse is over or near to the circle's line.

The added complication how ever is the circle is transformed at an angle so it's more of an ellipse. I can't see to get the code to detect that the mouse is near the border of circle and am unsure where I am going wrong.

This is my code:

```
function check(evt){
    var x = (evt.offsetX - element.width/2)  + camera.x; // world space
    var y = (evt.offsetY - element.height/2) + camera.y; // world space

    var threshold = 20/scale; //margin to edge of circle

    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length;i++){
       // var mainAngle is related to the transform
       var x1 = Math.pow((x - obj[i].originX), 2) / Math.pow((obj[i].radius + threshold) * 1,2);
       var y1 = Math.pow((y - obj[i].originY),2) / Math.pow((obj[i].radius + threshold) * mainAngle,2);
       var x0 = Math.pow((x - obj[i].originX),2) / Math.pow((obj[i].radius - threshold) * 1, 2);
       var y0 = Math.pow((y - obj[i].originY),2) / Math.pow((obj[i].radius - threshold) * mainAngle, 2);               

        if(x1 + y1 <= 1 && x0 + y0 >= 1){
            output.innerHTML += '<br/>Over';
            return false;
        }
    }
    output.innerHTML += '<br/>out';
}
```

To understand it better, I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nczbmbxm/ you can move the mouse over the circle, it should say "Over" when you are within the threshold of being near the circle's perimeter. Currently it does not seem to work. And I can't work out what the maths needs to be check for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo on line 34 with **orignX**

```
   var x1 = Math.pow((x - obj[i].orignX), 2) / Math.pow((obj[i].radius + threshold) * 1,2);
```

should be

```
   var x1 = Math.pow((x - obj[i].originX), 2) / Math.pow((obj[i].radius + threshold) * 1,2);
```

now you're good to go!

**EDIT:** In regards to the scaling of the image and further rotation of the circle, I would set up variables for rotation about the x-axis and y-axis, such as

```
var xAngle;
var yAngle;
```

then as an ellipse can be written in the form

```
x^2 / a^2 + y^2 / b^2 = 1
```

such as in [Euclidean Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#In_Euclidean_geometry),

then the semi-major and semi-minor axes would be determined by the rotation angles. If `radius` is the circles actual radius. then

```
var semiMajor = radius * cos( xAngle );
var semiMinor = radius;
```

or

```
var semiMajor = radius;
var semiMinor = radius * cos( yAngle );
```

you would still need to do some more transformations if you wanted an x and y angle.

so if `(xMouseC, yMouseC)` are the mouse coordinates relative to the circles centre, all you must do is check if that point satisfies the equation of the ellipse to within a certain tolerance, i.e. plug in

```
a = semiMajor;
b = semiMinor;
x = xMouseC;
y = yMouseC;
```

and see if it is sufficiently close to `1`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This doesn't totally solve the issue if you zoom the canvas the accuracy fails. But thanks for noticing the typo.

Comment: sorry, I should have looked into it a little more than that. I will take another look, it seems to just need some geometry to apply coordinate transformations

Comment: One thing i noticed was the threshold is less so on the y axis (because the circle is transformed) i don't know a way to thicken the threshold for that axis properly so the threshold is even around the entire circle.

Comment: I did mean to ask if the circle can only rotate about the x axis or both x and y?

Comment: I have not implemented an x axis rotation but if you show how to utilize the x axis as well that would be useful.

Comment: I'm just looking things over here, I thought it was rotated by 20 degree, but I see now you have a variable `mainAngle`, I am unsure how you have implemented that, so the `mainAngle = 1` which produces no rotation seems a little odd to me.

Comment: The main angle is applied to ctx.transform() function. Which gives the circle it's angle.

Comment: @Dave updated my answer, also it seems that you're having trouble detecting the mouse at any scale other than 1 is because when you scale out, coordinates don't scale appropriately; At `scale = 1.0` the coordinates for the cursor at the very top and centre of the ellipse is recorded as `(50, 440)` however at `scale = 2.0` the same "spot" on the ellipse is now recorded as being at `(50, 380)`.

Comment: Does your updated version also fix the scale issue such as an updated fiddle link?